# Using many label colours in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, labeling, color

I would like to label a polygon feature class by 1 attribute class; however I would like the colour of the text of the label to change dependent on the value of the attribute class

I know that in ArcMap there was a way this could be done by writing out a VB script formula, to define a colour to a certain value, but in this specific case I have at least 60 different values, and every one needs its own colour

I know it could be done by hand with the Label Classes, but it feels like there has to be a better way?

Comment: I would be questioning why anyone would want 60 alternate colours for labels? That's going to be a nightmare to understand for anyone looking at the map!

Comment: As a color-blind individual, I'd have to say that your plan isn't likely to pass muster in a Human Factors context, and even if they could, why would someone *try* to distinguish the significance of 60 different colors?

Comment: Im just the worker, that is the request of the boss, but say that I could get it down t o 15, how could it be done?

Comment: It's your job, as a cartographer, to push back, tactfully, on unwise requests. Given color, pattern, outline, marker and density to work with, surely you can come up with a better alternative. Even fifteen colors is two to three times too many. It's time to review the fundamentals of data presentation in color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this can be done - changing the colour of labels can be achieved like so:

```
import random

def FindLabel([ATTRIBUTE_TO_USE]):
    r = random.randint(0, 255)
    g = random.randint(0, 255)
    b = random.randint(0, 255)

    expression = f"<CLR red='{r}' green='{g}' blue='{b}'>" + [ATTRIBUTE_TO_USE]  + "</CLR>"
    return expression
```

The above scripts just generates random colours for each label and will reset every time. However, these random values could be saved to a new attribute in the attribute table called "RGB" or something similar. To do this:

```
import arcpy, random
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
map = aprx.listMaps()[0]
layer = map.listLayers("Name of your layer")
fields = [f.name for f in arcpy.Describe(layer).fields]
value _values = {}

# save each unique value with its own colour
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(layer, fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        value = row[fields.index("ATTR_NAME")]
        if attr not in value _values:
            r = random.randint(0, 255)
            g = random.randint(0, 255)
            b = random.randint(0, 255)
            random_rgb = (r, g, b)
            attr_values[value] = random_rgb

# for each row, match the attribute value to the colour
# save it as the value for the RGB attribute
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(layer, fields):
    for row in cursor:
        value = row[fields.index("ATTR_NAME")]
        random_rgb = attrToColour[value]
        row[fields.index("RGB")] = random_rgb
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

These values can then be accessed in labelling so that they don't regenerate every time.

```
def FindLabel([RBG]):
    r = RBG[0]
    g = RBG[1]
    b = RBG[2]

    expression = f"<CLR red='{r}' green='{g}' blue='{b}'>" + [ATTRIBUTE_TO_USE]  + "</CLR>"
    return expression
```

[Source](https://www.tutorialexample.com/generate-random-rgb-and-hex-color-in-python-a-step-guide-python-tutorial/)